# Present Modal view over Modal view not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I've had a look on SO and can't find an answer to this.  I'm presenting a modal view from:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     ICObservationEditController *controller = [[ICObservationEditController alloc] initWithObservation:[self.observations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
     navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
     navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
     [self.editController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Once presented, as an option I want to present a text message over the top from the `MessageUI` framework:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    NSLog(@"presented");

    //code here for text body

    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self.editController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

The debugger confirms I'm receiving the event, but no view is presented.  The code is correct as I have used the exact same code in other apps when not already in a modal view.

Comment: It is not a good practice to present a modal view from a view that is already being presented modally. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIKit won't allow this but there are workarounds. This [article](http://xissburg.com/presenting-multiple-modal-view-controllers-at-once/) should help you.